# When is the Killing form null?

Tags: lie-algebras

When is the Killing form $\kappa$ of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ null, i.e. $\kappa(\cdot,\cdot)=0$? Surely this is true for any Lie algebra with trivial bracket, but is this the only case? I can't seem to find any nontrivial examples.

Comment: You can go a bit better than trivial bracket: for any nilpotent Lie algebra the Killing form vanishes.

Comment: I see, thank you. And is also the converse true, in general? That is, does $\kappa$ null imply $\mathfrak g$ nilpotent?

Comment: In [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_criterion#Examples) it is mentioned that the converse is false. An example is given but I haven't checked it myself.

Comment: @WillieWong: I have checked all $3$-dimensional solvable Lie algebras -see below.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I saw, very nice. (Where did you think you got that upvote from? `:-)` )

Answer (score 16):

Suppose that $L$ is a finite-dimensional solvable Lie algebra over the complex numbers.
By Lie's theorem we may assume that all matrices of $ad(L)$ are upper-triangular.
If $L$, and hence $ad(L)$ is actually nilpotent, then they are even strictly upper-triangular, so that $\kappa(x,y)=tr (ad (x)ad(y))=0$ for all $x,y\in L$. Hence nilpotent Lie algebras have vanishing Killing form.

Conversely, let us consider the family $\mathfrak{r}_3(\lambda)$ of $3$-dimensional solvable, non-nilpotent Lie algebras, given by the brackets $[e_1,e_2]=e_2$ and $[e_1,e_3]=\lambda e_3$, with $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$. Then the Killing form satisfies $\kappa(e_i,e_j)=0$, except for $\kappa(e_1,e_1)=1+\lambda^2$. Now just take $\lambda=i$, with $i^2=-1$, and we have a solvable, non-nilpotent Lie algebra with vanishing Killing form.

Comment: when you say "by Lie's theorem we may assume that all matrices of ad(L) are upper-triangular" do you mean that there is a basis of L such that for all $x\in L$ the matrix of $ad(x)$ with respect to this matrix is upper triangular? Is this true generally for all finite dim. lie algebras? What statement of Lie's theorem do you use?

Comment: @gen I use the following corollary to Lie's theorem: *For all representations $\phi$ of a solvable Lie algebra $L$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over
an algebraically closed field $K$ of characteristic zero there exists a basis for $V$ for which the matrices
of $\phi(x)$ for all $x\in L$ are upper triangular.* You will find this in books on Lie algebras.

Comment: thank you (few more chars)